# Posting xml from classic asp to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, post, asp-classic

I apologize if this has been asked before.  I searched and didn't find anything that matched my situation.  Also bear in mind I am fairly new to asp/asp.net development.

My current project is a relatively simple e-commerce site.  The customer will connect to the site, select products, input shipping and billing information, payment information (credit card) and submit the order.

The project is being split into two parts:  The store front which includes displaying the items and taking the customer's shipping and billing information and the payment site which will collect the customers credit card, compute tax, and save the order into the company's system.  The reason that the site was split up, was that our side (payment side) already has facilities for credit card handling and tax computation.  There may also be some regulatory issues that the store front side does not want to deal with (which we already do).

I'm working on the payment portion of the app and I am using asp.net.  The store front side is being written in classic asp (not my decision).  Each part will be hosted on different servers.

The problem I am having is transferring the contents of the "shopping cart" to our app so that we can collect the cc info and submit the order.  We had thought that the classic asp could somehow post an xml fragment which contains the billing/shipping info and the items selected.  Our side would display a summary of the order, securely collect the credit card info, and submit the order to our system.  But I have been unable to post or send the xml from a classic asp on one server, to our asp.net application on another.  It all works just fine when I test on the same server.

How can I post (or otherwise transfer) the shopping cart data from classic asp to asp.net across server boundaries and transfer control to the asp.net application?

As I said, I am new to web development, so this is proving quite a challenge for me.

Comment: It might help you posted the working code, it would help us see why it doesn't work between machines.

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward ServerXMLHTTP code shouldn't have a problem going between machines.  Usually if the code is working locally but fails when separated on different machines then you need to start looking for Proxy server configs, authentication settings or name resolution as the culprits.

Some code and description of the actual failure/error message would help?

Comment: There was no failure message.  It turned out that I omitted the name attribute from the hidden input tag so it was not included in the request.form object.  Once I added that attribute, it seemed to work ok.  I have much to learn still!